# MVC Remote validation is not rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, remote-validation

I have a model called ItemCodeModel that is defined outside of my MVC
project (in a different project).  Here is the model below:

```cs
public class ItemCodeModel
    {

        public Guid ItemId {get; set;}

        [Required]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]*$", ErrorMessage = "Item Code requires alphabet or number")]
        [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Item Code must be less than 5 characters.")]
        [Remote("ItemCodeExists", "Validation", ErrorMessage = "Item Code already exists.")]
        [Display(Name = "Item Code")]
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Item Description must be less than 100 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "Item Description")]
        public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    }
```

In my MVC project, I have the below function in my ValidationController:

```cs
public JsonResult ItemCodeExists(string ItemCode)
```

Then, EditItemCodeView contains the following syntax for property ItemCode:

```cs
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ItemCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

The issue I'm having is that my view is rendering this:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="ItemCode" name="ItemCode" type="text" value="XXXX" />
```

Instead of rendering all of the data-val attributes decorated on ItemCode property of ItemCodeModel:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="Item Code must be less than 5 characters." data-val-length-max="5" data-val-regex="Item Code requires alphabet or number" data-val-regex-pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$" data-val-remote="ItemCode already exists." data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.ItemCode" data-val-remote-url="/Validation/ItemCodeExists" data-val-required="The Item Code field is required." id="ItemCode" name="ItemCode" type="text" value="XXXX" />
```

Since these attributes are missing, validations are not being triggered.  If I remove the [Remote] declaration from ItemCode, the view correctly renders all data annotations and validations are triggered.  Having the remote validation decoration somehow removes these attributes from the view in addition to not rendering itself.

However, if I define the same model within the MVC project in the Models folder, the view correctly renders all required data-val attributes and validation is triggered.

Is there something I'm missing by creating the model in a separate library and having the MVC project reference it?

Comment: `[Remote("ItemCode", ...` does not match `public JsonResult ItemCodeExists` (is that a typo?)

Comment: Have  you enabled `ClientValidationEnabled` and `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` in web.config ? [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx)

Comment: Stephen, yes that was a typo, thanks for the correcting me.  Searching, ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavascriptEnabled are enabled

Comment: @user2472888 A common cause for validation attributes not being is that you have another input for the same property before this one. There is nothing different about it being in a separate .dll, but its unclear why you would want to do that (for a data model its fine, but view models relate directly to your view so should be in the same project)

Comment: @StephenMuecke The intent was to separate business and data access functions from the main project into their own libraries so that they can easily be switched out or reused if needed. Since Entity is used to connect to the db, a separate project is then built for data models that is used to transfer information between the business and data layers and the view models were thrown in there as well.

Comment: Its fine to have your data models in a separate `.dll` but what you have shown is not (or at least should not be) your data model - its decorated with `[Remote]` and `[Display]` attributes which are view specific attributes and should not be applied to data models (only to the view models you use in the view)

Comment: I see...so in this case if I have a data model and the view model is exactly the same as the data model, I should still create a view model with the exact same properties with the only difference being that the decorated attributes are on the view model instead of the data model?  Currently, the only time I create a view model instead of using the data model in the view is if additional info is required to be returned in the view.  For example if I want to display a dropdown with a list of valid values coming from a different table for a certain field.